# How can I parse this date format into datetime? Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, datetime-format

The starting date format I currently have is `2019-09-04 16:00 UTC+3` and I'm trying to convert it into a datetime format of `2019-09-04 16:00:00+0300`.

The format I thought would work was `format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %Z%z'`, but when I run it I get the error message `ValueError: Cannot parse both %Z and %z`.

Does anyone know the correct format to use, or should I be trying a different method altogether? Thanks.

**Edit**
Sorry, I had a hard time putting into words what it is I am looking to do, hopefully I can clarify.

I'm looking to change all the date and times in a dataframe into the datetime format.

This is the method I was trying to use which presented me with an error
`df['datepicker'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datepicker'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %Z%z')`

And here is a sample of the data I currently have.

```
datepicker
2019-09-07 16:00 UTC+2
2019-09-04 18:30 UTC+4
2019-09-06 17:00 UTC±0
2019-09-10 16:00 UTC+1
2019-09-04 18:00 UTC+3
```

And this is what I'm looking to convert them into, a timestamp format.

```
datepicker
2019-09-07 16:00:00+0200
2019-09-04 18:30:00+0400
2019-09-06 17:00:00+0000
2019-09-10 16:00:00+0100
2019-09-04 18:00:00+0300
```

Comment: Where is the code snippet that you tried?

Comment: I've added more details to my original post, could you check it out again, please?

Comment: is the UTC offset always represented as a single digit hour? or can there also be appear things like '+5:30' e.g. for asia/kolkata time zone?

Comment: @MrFuppes I'd like to make it able to handle all timezones preferably, so yeah things like asia/Kolkata or asia/Tehran need to be handled correctly too. Changing the ```±``` to a ```+``` seems to have solved everything, it's just now the time stamps are showing the opposite UTC time +4 is now -4, any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot, it works fine. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas.to_datetime` should parse this happily if you tweak the strings slightly:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"datepicker":[ "2019-09-07 16:00 UTC+2", "2019-09-04 18:30 UTC+4",
                                  "2019-09-06 17:00 UTC±0", "2019-09-10 16:00 UTC+1", 
                                  "2019-09-04 18:00 UTC+3"]})
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datepicker'].str.replace('±', '+'))
# df['datetime']
# 0    2019-09-07 16:00:00-02:00
# 1    2019-09-04 18:30:00-04:00
# 2    2019-09-06 17:00:00+00:00
# 3    2019-09-10 16:00:00-01:00
# 4    2019-09-04 18:00:00-03:00
# Name: datetime, dtype: object
```

Note that due to the mixed UTC offsets, the column's data type is 'object' (datetime objects). If you wish, you can also convert to UTC straight away, to get a column of dtype datetime[ns]:

```
df['UTC'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datepicker'].str.replace('±', '+'), utc=True)
# df['UTC']
# 0   2019-09-07 18:00:00+00:00
# 1   2019-09-04 22:30:00+00:00
# 2   2019-09-06 17:00:00+00:00
# 3   2019-09-10 17:00:00+00:00
# 4   2019-09-04 21:00:00+00:00
# Name: UTC, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

Answer (score 0):

When i defined as below. it works as you expect.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

UTC = timezone(timedelta(hours=+3))
dt = datetime(2019, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=UTC)
timestampStr = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %Z%z")
print(timestampStr)
```

With the output of:

```
2019-01-01 12:00 UTC+03:00+0300
```